# Magento 2.4 How can I exclude products from the products widget

Tags: magento, widget, magento2

I need to exclude some products from the product grid widget in Magento 2.4 based on the value of a custom attribute set on the product.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In the attribute you need to go to Storefront Properties and turn Use for Promo Rules Conditions to YES and Used in Product Listing to YES.
Then when you insert the widget in the conditions you will see the attribute